# How do I create/play audio in C++?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, audio, frequency

I'm pretty new to C++, but have some experience with Python. I wanted to make a program that played certain frequencies based on different conditions, but I soon realized I couldn't even figure out how to play an audio file. From what I found looking for a solution, it seems almost impossible on Mac, and everything I tried copying into Xcode ended up with a bunch of errors. Where should I start with this?

Comment: Look for a library that can play sounds, and then go through its manuals/examples.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssound?language=objc

Comment: @PaulSanders the problem here is that `NSSound` only has Objective-c and Swift interfaces. Yes, the OP could use Objective-C++, but I'd say that is straying too far from path. Fundamentally, the problem is that there are no straight C++ interfaces for audio. At best, you can use a wrapper library if interfacing with the native APIs or you're going to have to some cross-platform API, which for the most part seem to be straight C.

Comment: @fdcpp Sure, but writing a C or C++ wrapper for the Objective-C version of `NSSound` is simple enough.  I do that sort of thing all the time.

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes it is simple if you are already familiar with the constituent parts, but would you say it is _likely_ that the OP is coming from that same background ?

Comment: @fdcpp No, probably not, but (unlike C++), Objective-C is not a hard language to learn.

Comment: @PaulSanders I disagree, I started with C and Python and avoided ObjC for a very long time as it’s structure was very unintuitive. I think it depends on your perspective, but it’s best to assume that it will _**not**_ be easy for someone else to learn.

Comment: Why is this 'opinion based'?  The OP is asking how to do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that C++ is *just a programming language*. The same can be said for python, though Python lives in a different ecosystem of modules and package management which get conflated (rightly or wrongly) as *part of the language*

C++ doesn’t have the same history and the same ecosystem and this is part of the battle you will have when learning it. You don’t have `pip`, you have a nebulous series of frameworks, headers and libraries (some standard, some which need installation) all of which need linked, path-ed or compiled. It is an ecosystem that is unfriendly if you try and approach it like a novice Python programmer. If you approach it agnostically, it is simultaneously very powerful and exceptionally tedious, a combination that tends to polarise developers.

This means that simple answers like *Use SFML!, SDL, NSOUND, OpenAL, CoreAudio, AVFoundation, JUCE, &c...* are all technically "correct" but massively gloss over large parts of setup, nomenclature and workflow that are just a `pip install` away with python.

Pontificating aside, if you want to simply

- create an array of floating point values
- that represent the samples of sine tone
- then play those samples
- on macOS

Then you are probably best just

- creating your array
- writing a `.wav`
- opening the `.wav` with `afplay`

Is that the *most open, versatile, DSP orientated, play-from-RAM* solution? No, of course not, but it is *a* solution to the problem you pose here. The alternative and correct answer is an exhaustive list of every major media library, cross-platform and macOS specific, their setup, quirks and minimum working example, which would result in an answer so obtusely long I hope you can sympathise with why it is not best addressed on Stack Overflow.

### A Simple CLI App

You can find all the constituent parts of this on SO, but I have tallied-off so many *how do I play a sound in C++* questions it has made me realise they are not going away.

The setup for Xcode is to create a Command Line Tool project (Console App for Visual Studio).

Here is a header that will wrap up everything into a `playSound` function

#### audio.h

```cpp
#pragma once

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>
#if defined _WIN32 || defined _WIN64
#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm")
#include <windows.h>
#endif
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/// <#Description#>
struct WaveHeader
{
    /** waveFormatHeader: The first 4 bytes of a wav file should be the characters "RIFF" */
    char chunkID[4] = { 'R', 'I', 'F', 'F' };
    /** waveFormatHeader: This is the size of the entire file in bytes minus 8 bytes */
    uint32_t chunkSize;
    /** waveFormatHeader" The should be characters "WAVE" */
    char format[4] = { 'W', 'A', 'V', 'E' };
    /** waveFormatHeader" This should be the letters "fmt ", note the space character */
    char subChunk1ID[4] = { 'f', 'm', 't', ' ' };
    /** waveFormatHeader: For PCM == 16, since audioFormat == uint16_t */
    uint32_t subChunk1Size = 16;
    /** waveFormatHeader: For PCM this is 1, other values indicate compression */
    uint16_t audioFormat = 1;
    /** waveFormatHeader: Mono = 1, Stereo = 2, etc. */
    uint16_t numChannels = 1;
    /** waveFormatHeader: Sample Rate of file */
    uint32_t sampleRate = 44100;
    /** waveFormatHeader: SampleRate * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8 */
    uint32_t byteRate = 44100 * 2;
    /** waveFormatHeader: The number of bytes for one sample including all channels */
    uint16_t blockAlign = 2;
    /** waveFormatHeader: 8 bits = 8, 16 bits = 16 */
    uint16_t bitsPerSample = 16;
    /** waveFormatHeader: Contains the letters "data" */
    char subChunk2ID[4] = { 'd', 'a', 't', 'a' };
    /** waveFormatHeader: == NumberOfFrames * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
     This is the number of bytes in the data.
     */
    uint32_t subChunk2Size;
    
    WaveHeader(uint32_t samplingFrequency = 44100, uint16_t bitDepth = 16, uint16_t numberOfChannels = 1)
    {
        numChannels = numberOfChannels;
        sampleRate = samplingFrequency;
        bitsPerSample = bitDepth;
        
        byteRate = sampleRate * numChannels * bitsPerSample / 8;
        blockAlign = numChannels * bitsPerSample / 8;
    };
    
    /// sets the fields that refer to how large the wave file is
    /// @warning This MUST be set before writing a file, or the file will be unplayable.
    /// @param numberOfFrames total number of audio frames. i.e. total number of samples / number of channels
    void setFileSize(uint32_t numberOfFrames)
    {
        subChunk2Size = numberOfFrames * numChannels * bitsPerSample / 8;
        chunkSize = 36 + subChunk2Size;
    }
    
};

/// write an array of float data to a 16-bit, 44100 Hz Mono wav file in the same directory as the program and then play it
/// @param audio audio samples, assumed to be 44100 Hz sampling rate
/// @param numberOfSamples total number of samples in audio
/// @param filename filename, should end in .wav and will be written to your Desktop
void playSound(float* audio,
               uint32_t numberOfSamples,
               const char* filename)
{
    std::ofstream fs;
    std::string filepath {filename};
    
    if (filepath.substr(filepath.size() - 4, 4) != std::string(".wav"))
        filepath += std::string(".wav");
    
    fs.open(filepath, std::fstream::out | std::ios::binary);
    
    WaveHeader* header = new WaveHeader{};
    header->setFileSize(numberOfSamples);
    
    fs.write((char*)header, sizeof(WaveHeader));
    
    int16_t* audioData = new int16_t[numberOfSamples];
    constexpr float max16BitValue = 32768.0f;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSamples; ++i)
    {
        int pcm = int(audio[i] * (max16BitValue));
        
        if (pcm >= max16BitValue)
            pcm = max16BitValue - 1;
        else if (pcm < -max16BitValue)
            pcm = -max16BitValue;
        
        audioData[i] = int16_t(pcm);
    }
    
    
    fs.write((char*)audioData, header->subChunk2Size);
    
    fs.close();
    std::cout << filename << " written to:\n" << filepath << std::endl;
    
    
#if defined _WIN32 || defined _WIN64
    // don't forget to add Add 'Winmm.lib' in Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies
    PlaySound(std::wstring(filepath.begin(), filepath.end()).c_str(), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
#else
    std::system((std::string("afplay ") + filepath).c_str());
#endif
    
}
```

#### main.cpp

Your `main` function could then be something like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "audio.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const int numSamples = 44100;
    float sampleRate = 44100.0f;
    float* sineWave = new float[numSamples];
    float frequency = 440.0f;
    
    float radsPerSamp = 2.0f * 3.1415926536f * frequency / sampleRate;
    
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < numSamples; i++)
    {
        sineWave[i] = std::sin (radsPerSamp * (float) i);
    }
    
    playSound(sineWave, numSamples, "test.wav");
        
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I once used [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) for this. Although I did it on Linux, I see that its available for mac as well. You can go through the tutorials [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-osx.php).